# Series of books about a private school full of werewolves

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

Trying to remember series of books about a teenage girl that starts attending a school full of werewolves. I seem to remember more of a thriller than a horror.

Comment: That is not much to go on. Do you remember anything else? When did you read it? Where? What did the books look like? What happened in them? You can [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Hello, please make sure you've checked out the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about *[Werewolf Academy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MQ7N2AK)* by Cheree Alsop?

[image: Werewolf Academy - Book Cover]

> Werewolves are struggling to survive. Jaze and those who remain of his pack build an Academy to protect the children who endured the genocide. Alex and Cassie arrive as orphans after losing everyone they love. The twins find themselves in a new world where they have to survive the politics and dangers of being a werewolf in a world that wants them destroyed.
>   But outside forces have found them. Can Alex protect his sister and survive the attacks of a man who wants them dead and will stop at nothing to see it happen?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not everyone who's werewolves, this could be the *[Private School](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6346206-nightmare-session)* series by Steven Charles, which has teachers which are alien shapeshifters that turn into wolves, most prominently in the fifth book, *[The Enemy Within](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11944567-the-enemy-within)*.

[image: Private School #5 - The Enemy Within - Book Cover]

> The aliens were taking over. At first, Jennifer thought the horrible menace was confined to posh Thaler Academy. But now, she and her friends were beginning to realize that no one could be trusted. Not even the police.
>
> The terror was growing. The hideous creatures that roamed the school grounds assumed human forms. And worse yet, the unearthly beasts knew about Jennifer-and her plan to expose them. Could she stop the escalating nightmare before the aliens bound the key to Earth's ultimate destruction?